# Conditional borders in Google SpreadSheet

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I would like to have yellow borders on cells that are column's maximum as follows:

[image]

That is, I need to have conditional borders. I understood I should use Google Scripting but I have no idea nor knowledge how to do that, could you help?

Note that I have hundred of cells, not only a few where I could do it by hand :).

Comment: Is your main condition that a column's maximum value should be formatted in a specific way?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.
If you're asking whether it is [possible to set conditional formatting on a cell based on another cell's value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/how-can-i-set-conditional-formatting-on-a-particular-cell-that-depends-on-anothe), then that is already possible with a custom formula.
If you're asking whether it is [possible to have conditional borders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84848/automatically-add-borders-around-nonempty-cells), then you will need to write a script to do it.

Comment: @dougwoodrow, yes you are right, I want to ask whether I can have conditional borders. I edited my question thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****EDIT****

Thank you for clarifying! Here are some quick edits to the script to make it run on sheet of arbitrary row and columns, format the cell with the largest value with a medium weight yellow border. Threw this together quickly, but I hope it helps!

```
function JKHAScript() {
  //get the first sheet of the currently active google spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var NumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var NumColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  //loop through each column skipping the first row, (j,i) is the (row#, column#)
  for (let i = 1; i <= NumColumns; i++) {
    var LargestCell = sheet.getRange(2,1);
    for (let j = 2; j <= NumRows; j++) { 
      let IndexCell = sheet.getRange(j, i);
      //one pass through each column, grabs the largest value
        if (IndexCell.getValue() > LargestCell.getValue()) {
              LargestCell = IndexCell;
            }
        }
      //after pass, the cell with the largest value gets the border formatting
      LargestCell.setBorder(true,true,true,true,null,null, "yellow", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)
    }
}
```

To run a script over a google sheet: open your sheet, go to the tools tab, click the scripts editor. *Only paste code you trust into the editor!!* Click run at the top of the page to execute the script on whatever sheet you had currently open. Should look something like this:

[image: Editor for scripts]

****ORIGINAL****

Forgive me if I misunderstand, but I believe your issue can be solved using **google app scripts**. I am not sure exactly what formatting you want to perform but here is a simple example that runs on a little 11 by 4 sheet with random numbers. Of course, you will need to modify it to work on your sheet, and perform whatever formatting you wish to apply.

```
function JKHAScript() {
  //get the first sheet of the currently active google spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //loop through each column skipping the first row, (j,i) is the (row#, column#)
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var LargestCell = sheet.getRange(2,1);
    for (let j = 2; j <=11; j++) { 
      let IndexCell = sheet.getRange(j, i);
      //one pass through each column, grabs the largest value
        if (IndexCell.getValue() > LargestCell.getValue()) {
              LargestCell = IndexCell;
            }
        }
      //after pass, the cell with the largest value gets the border formatting
      LargestCell.setBorder(true,true,true,true,null,null, "yellow", null)
    }
}
```

**Before running**

[image: My example sheet]

*After running*

[image: After the script runs.]

This is a slow and lame example. [You can find more information about google app scripts here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script?hl=en) Good luck scripting my friend!